# "&optional" in (prettify-symbols-mode &optional ARG)

Tags: lisp, elisp

using Emacs Lisp:

Upon invoking `describe-function` to review `prettify-symbols-mode`

```
(prettify-symbols-mode &optional ARG)
```

What does `&optional` mean? is `&` is a 'logand'?

Comment: `M-x elisp-index-search RET &optional RET`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

&optional in an argument list mean that the arguments that follow are not required.  If the caller provides them then they'll be assigned to the respective variables.  If not, then the variables will be nil.

See also https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Argument-List.html

The '&' in front of 'optional' makes it possible for the defun to recognize '&optional' as a keyword and not an argument itself.

Comment: `&optional` is a different symbol object from `optional`. The `eq` function tells us so; we don't have to go down to the character level to look at the ampersand in the name.